# Obtaining pandas timeseries plot axis limits (without using x_compat=True)

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am using pandas version 0.25.3 and matplotlib 3.1.1

Take the following dataframe with a DatetimeIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'v':[1,2,3]}, index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00:00',end='2019-01-01 00:00:00.1',periods=3,name='time'))
```

It looks like this:

```
                         v
time                      
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000  1
2019-01-01 00:00:00.050  2
2019-01-01 00:00:00.100  3
```

When this is plotted with `df.plot()`, an attempt to obtain the datetime corresponding to the left or right edge of the plot fails:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
mdates.num2date(plt.gca().get_xlim()[0])   
...
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

You also get other types of errors depending on the datetime values in the dataframe (sometimes you get `ValueError: year xxx is out of range`).

I have managed to establish that a way round this is to disable the pandas automatic tick resolution features, i.e. if you do:

```
df.plot(x_compat=True)
mdates.num2date(plt.gca().get_xlim()[0])
```

this works (gives `datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)`).

But surely there is a way to correctly obtain the datetime without using this workaround? I can see on the matplotlib window that the time is correctly displayed as I move the cursor around on the screen (interesting note: the window shows "t = XXXXX" rather than "x = XXXXXX" when I use pandas default plotting). What method is the matplotlib window calling to obtain the time string to display?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this one, it's bugging me that it must be possible?

Comment: The method called for getting the string in the window is [this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c5576293859f4351e508471811948e9a1dac4a30/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/timeseries.py#L309). But that won't give you the datetime, right? Since pandas does not work with datetimes internally, I suspect that this is pretty hard.

Comment: Actually you might have got to the answer. Doing: `pd.Period(ordinal=int(plt.gca().get_xlim()[0]),freq=plt.gca().freq)` looks sensible ... running some tests now then will post an answer if confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following comment ImportanceOfBeingErnest, a solution appears to be:

```
pd.Period(ordinal=int(plt.gca().get_xlim()[0]),freq=plt.gca().freq).to_timestamp()
```